# Proof of the generating function of $1 -2x +3x^2 -4x^3+5x^4-6x^5+\cdots$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, power-series

The ordinary generating function for the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq0}$ where $a_n = (-1)^n\,n$ is

$$1 -2x +3x^2 -4x^3+5x^4-6x^5+\cdots = \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$$

I can see from the geometric formula, and even from long division that

$$1 -x +x^2 -x^3+x^4-x^5+\cdots = \frac{1}{1+x}$$

but I'm not seeing the coefficients to explain $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$S_n = 1 -2x +3x^2 -4x^3+5x^4-6x^5+\cdots$$ $$\implies
  xS_n = x - 2x^2 + 3x^3 -\cdots$$
$$(1+x)S_n=1-x+x^2-x^3\cdots=\frac{1}{1+x}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$S=1 -x +x^2 -x^3+x^4-x^5+\cdots = \frac{1}{1+x}$$
Take the derivative
$$S'=0 -1 +2x -3x^2+4x^3-5x^4+\cdots = \frac{-1}{(1+x)^2}$$
Multiply by $-1$
$$-S'=1 -2x +3x^2-4x^3+5x^4+\cdots = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}(-1)^k(k+1)x^k = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Just to be different.

$\dfrac1{1-x}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{(1-x)^2}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^m\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^{m+n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{k} x^{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{k}\sum_{m=0}^{k}1\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1) x^{k}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac1{(1+x)^2}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)(-1)^k x^{k}\\
\end{array}
$